# Parse selected form value into jQuery.ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this drop down form - doing a sorting call.

What I can't manage to do is to parse the current selected value from the form in the ajax. URL.

The Form:

```
<form name="sortby">
    <select name="order_by" onchange="myFunction()">
        <option<?php if(isset($_GET['order_by']) && $_GET['order_by'] == 'choose') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?> value="choose">Sort By</option>
        <option<?php if(isset($_GET['order_by']) && $_GET['order_by'] == 'OVERALL_VALUE') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?> value="OVERALL_VALUE">Most Popular</option>
        <option<?php if(isset($_GET['order_by']) && $_GET['order_by'] == 'PRICE') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?> value="PRICE">Price (low to high)</option>
        <option<?php if(isset($_GET['order_by']) && $_GET['order_by'] == 'PRICE_REVERSE') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?> value="PRICE_REVERSE">Price (high to low)</option>
        <option<?php if(isset($_GET['order_by']) && $_GET['order_by'] == 'QUALITY') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?> value="QUALITY">Rating</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

The ajax.

```
    <script>
    function myFunction() { 
    $('.searchtable').addClass('hide');
    $('.spinner').removeClass('hide');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: {'name':'<?php echo $name;?>','arrival':'<?php echo $arrival;?>','departure':'<?php echo $departure;?>','guests':'<?php echo $numberOfGuests;?>','order_by':$('#order_by').value},
        url: 'hotels/hotelSortBy.php',


        success: function (data) {
            //alert('data loaded succesfully');
            alert(this.url);

            $('.searchtable').replaceWith(data);

        },
        error: function (xhr) {
                                   alert('data not loaded');

            // do what ever you want to do when error happens
        }
 })

 .done(function() {
 $('.spinner').addClass('hide');
 $('.searchtable').removeClass('hide');
 });

 }
 </script>
```

hotelSortBy.php

```
<?php 
$url  = 'xxx';
$url .= '&cid=55505';
$url .= 'xxxx';
//$url .= '&customerUserAgent='[xxx]
//$url .= '&customerIpAddress='[xxx]
$url .= '&locale=da_DK';
$url .= '&currencyCode=DKK';
$url .= '&destinationString=' .  strval($_GET['name']);
$url .= '&supplierCacheTolerance=MED_ENHANCED';
$url .= '&searchRadius=50';
$url .= '&arrivalDate=' . strval($_GET['arrival']);
$url .= '&departureDate=' . strval($_GET['departure']);
$url .= '&room' . strval($_GET['rooms']) . '=' . strval($_GET['numberOfGuests']) . ',,';
$url .= '&sort='. strval($_GET['order_by']);
$url .= '&numberOfResults=20';
$header[] = "Accept: application/json";
$header[] = "Accept-Encoding: gzip";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header );
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
 curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
 curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
 $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
 include '/hotelTables.php';

 ?>
```

Order_by value from the form is not pasted into ajax data to apply to the url.

Comment: Check out where it says Instead within the code. When you select an option in the form - I want to parse that selected option value to the url: where it says `hotels/hotelSortBy.php?&order_by=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need an `id` not just a `name` attribute:

```
<select id="order_by" name="order_by" onchange="myFunction()">

         ^^^^ id
```

Then put the value of `order_by` in the `data` section, not the url. Mixing data section and putting query params explicitly in the url is a bad idea as some params could get lost in some browsers when doing that. Choose one or the other:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    data:
    {
       'order_by':$('#order_by').val(),
       'name': '<?php echo $name;?>',
       'arrival': '<?php echo $arrival;?>',
       'departure': '<?php echo $departure;?>',
       'guests': '<?php echo $numberOfGuests;?>'
    },
    url: 'hotels/hotelSortBy.php',
    .....
```

I question the wisdom of printing all that PHP in there. I think probably those should be fields in the form, even if hidden fields (i.e. `<input type='hidden' />`).

Comment: Tried this but the value is not parsed. `type: 'GET',
            data: {'name':'<?php echo $name;?>','arrival':'<?php echo $arrival;?>','departure':'<?php echo $departure;?>','guests':'<?php echo $numberOfGuests;?>','order_by':$('#order_by').value},`

Comment: `<select id="order_by" name="order_by" onchange="myFunction()">`

Comment: `url: 'hotels/hotelSortBy.php',`

Comment: @TroelsJohannesen This will ensure that the value from the dropdown makes it into your ajax request. I don't know if your ajax request will then work or not, because you didn't post the full code of the `$.ajax()` function, nor what your hotelSortBy.php is doing...so I imagine whatever error you are now encountering is in something missing further down in `$.ajax()` or in hotelSortBy.php

Comment: @TroelsJohannesen You also didn't make it clear whether you're attempting that ajax inside `myFunction()` or what, but I suppose that is where it should be.

Comment: I pasted full code of the two documents you asked for. Ajax is within myFunction() - is that an issue?

Comment: @TroelsJohannesen You're trying to use two different contradictory jquery tutorials. `.done()` is a newer replacement for `success()`: you can't mix them. Choose one. Again, just like trying to put some variables in `data` and others in the url. Don't mix completely different approaches.

Comment: true I corrected that! - Thanks! Very confusing on those overlapping methods in jQuery.

Comment: When I replace $('.order_by').value with just 'PRICE' - it is parsed - but it seems like this one: $('.order_by').value is not parsing the value correctly ?

Comment: @TroelsJohannesen It should be `$('#order_by').value` not `$('.order_by').value`. In your jquery selector, `#` refers to an element's `id` and `.` to a css `className`.

Comment: Found the issue - partly the class/id thing you mention - but that didn't solve it . What solve it was using the version like this: 'order_by':$('#order_by').val() - parses the value correctly. Thanks for your help - really appreciated! @developerwjk

Comment: @TroelsJohannesen Oh yeah, I guess `.value` is when you use plan js `document.getElementById('id').value` but jquery shortened it to `$('#id').val()` ...stupid jquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    data: {'name':'<?php echo $name;?>','arrival':'<?php echo $arrival;?>','departure':'<?php echo $departure;?>','guests':'<?php echo $numberOfGuests;?>'},
    url: 'hotels/hotelSortBy.php?&order_by='+$('form').find('select').val(),
```

Comment: Mixing data section and putting query params explicitly in the url is just asking for some browser to drop off some of your params.